# How can I connect the internet by wifi?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-connectivitymanager

When android device is not connected to the Internet,
I'm going to check if Wi-Fi can be connected with connection live data and connect to a specific Wi-Fi.

**ConnectionLiveData**

```
private val TAG = "ConnectionLiveData"

class ConnectionLiveData(context: Context) : LiveData<Boolean>() {

    private lateinit var networkCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback

    private val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    private val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

    private val validNetworks: MutableSet<Network> = HashSet()

    private fun checkValidNetworks() {
        postValue(validNetworks.size > 0)
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        networkCallback = createNetworkCallback()
        val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .build()
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
    }

    private fun createNetworkCallback() = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            Log.d(TAG, "---Location onAvailable: $network")
            val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
            val hasInternetCapability = networkCapabilities?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            Log.d(TAG, "---Location onAvailable: $network, $hasInternetCapability")
            if (hasInternetCapability == true) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    val hasInternet = DoesNetworkHaveInternet.execute(network.socketFactory)
                    if (hasInternet) {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAvailable: adding network. $network")
                            validNetworks.add(network)
                            checkValidNetworks()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else {
                Log.d(TAG, "There is no active network")
            }
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                "The application no longer has a default network. The last default network was $network"
            )
            validNetworks.remove(network)
            checkValidNetworks()
        }

        override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
            network: Network,
            networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The default network changed capabilities: $networkCapabilities")
        }

        override fun onLinkPropertiesChanged(
            network: Network,
            linkProperties: LinkProperties
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The default network changed link properties: $linkProperties")
        }
    }
}
```

**ConnectivityManager**

```
@Singleton
class ConnectivityManager
@Inject
constructor(
    application: Application,
) {
    private val connectionLiveData = ConnectionLiveData(application)

    // observe this in ui
    val isNetworkAvailable = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun registerConnectionObserver(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner){
        connectionLiveData.observe(lifecycleOwner) { isConnected ->
            isConnected?.let { isNetworkAvailable.value = it }
        }
    }

    fun unregisterConnectionObserver(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner){
        connectionLiveData.removeObservers(lifecycleOwner)
    }
}
```

And then, when I connect the wifi, it logs like this.

```
2021-11-27 10:09:10.808 28100-28143/com.connectapp D/ConnectionLiveData: ---Location onAvailable: 152
2021-11-27 10:09:10.810 28100-28143/com.connectapp D/ConnectionLiveData: ---Location onAvailable: 152, true
2021-11-27 10:09:10.812 28100-28143/com.connectapp D/ConnectionLiveData: The default network changed capabilities: [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps SignalStrength: -56]
2021-11-27 10:09:10.814 28100-28143/com.connectapp D/ConnectionLiveData: The default network changed link properties: {Network Interface}
2021-11-27 10:09:10.885 28100-28100/com.connectapp D/ConnectionLiveData: onAvailable: adding network. 152
```

But when I remove stored Wi-Fi data at device, it doesn't return Log
So my question is this, when android device is not connected to internet, connect to specific Wi-Fi.
How I can connect it?

Comment: Without referring to documentation I am assuming there is no way they would make it possible for apps to do this because of security reasons.

Comment: @Thenfour04 Could you tell me more about security reasons?